# Send a json File to a pug template with Express and Node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

Forgive me but Im still a bit new to express. I have a pug template running a simple homepage. On the same server I have a json file containing a lists of events. I want to send the data in this json file to the pug template and iterate over it in a div. I have used fs to load the file, lodash map to map it to an array. I have created the route for the pug file but I don't know how to link the two together i.e pass the array created in my fs function to the jade route. I have the below so far

```
var file = __dirname + '/events.json';
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
if (err) {
  console.log('Error: ' + err);
  return;
}

var data = JSON.parse(data);

var newEventList = data.events.map(events => ({
    id: events.id ,
    name: events.name ,
    venue: events.place.name ,
    address: events.place.location.street + " " + events.place.location.city + " " + events.place.location.zip ,
    coverPicture: events.coverPicture ,
    description: events.description ,
    startTime: events.startTime ,
    endTime: events.endTime
 }));
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!', 
   newEventList })
  })
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction? At the moment I get

```
ReferenceError: newEventList is not defined
```

So I guess I need a way to make the route see the newEventList array. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing isn't working because:

a) You don't do anything with the `data` argument within your callback to `readFile`

b) node.js is asynchronous and so the parsing of the data and also `app.get` will run before your callback has finished anyway

A nice easy solution would be to just replace all of this:

```
var file = __dirname + '/events.json';
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
if (err) {
  console.log('Error: ' + err);
  return;
}
```

with

```
var data = require('./events.json')
```

which will run synchronously, so that the variable `data` is always available.

alternatively, if you want to use `fs` for any reason (for practice and your understanding or whatever), you will need to do all of that within the callback to `app.get('/')`. And assign the data you get back to a variable *inside* the callback.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I'm slowly getting my head around node and this really helps!